# How do you make the \in symbol smaller?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, fontsize

By default, `\in` produces a lunate epsilon that is just a crazy, ridiculous size.

What is the most correct way to make it smaller?

Comment: What about using {\fontsize{8pt}{\baselineskip}\in}?

Comment: You can find an excellent answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82706/23931) by Heiko Oberdiek.